# assembly getting the sum of inputs

Tags: assembly, sum, dos, x86-16

I have a problem in assembly in which I could not get the sum and product of  2 inputted numbers. I'm still working on getting the sum, but it seems like I could not get it. I'm using emu8086. Could you help me fixing these codes below. I Could not also get their products yet. i'm a newbie. Thanks.

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 1000
.DATA
MSGA DB 13,10,"Input first number: ","$"
MSGB DB 13,10,"Input second number:","$"
MSGC DB 13,10,"The sum is: ","$"
NUM1 db ?
NUM2 db ?
NUM3 db ?
.CODE
MAIN PROC NEAR
MOV AX, @DATA
MOV DS, AX
LEA DX, MSGA
MOV AH, 09h
INT 21h
MOV AH, 01
INT 21H
SUB AL, '0'
MOV BL, AL
MOV AH, 01
INT 21H
SUB AL, '0'
MOV CL, AL
LEA DX, MSGB
MOV AH, 09h
INT 21h
MOV AH, 01
INT 21H
SUB AL, '0'
MOV DL, AL
MOV AH, 01
INT 21H
SUB AL, '0'
MOV DH, AL
MOV AL, CL
MOV AH, BL
ADD AL, DH
AAA
ADD AH, DL
MOV NUM1, AL
ADD NUM1, '0'
CMP AH, 9
JLE NOT_3DIGIT
IS_3DIGIT:
MOV AL, AH   
SUB AH, AH   
ADD AL, 0    
AAA          
ADD AH, 0    
MOV NUM2, AL
MOV NUM3, AH
ADD NUM2, '0'
ADD NUM3, '0'
LEA DX, MSGC
MOV AH, 09h
INT 21h
MOV DL, NUM3
MOV AH, 02H
INT 21h
MOV DL, NUM2
MOV AH, 02H
INT 21h   
JMP PRINT_LASTDIGIT  


NOT_3DIGIT:
MOV NUM2, AH
ADD NUM2, '0'
LEA DX, MSGC
MOV AH, 09h
INT 21h
MOV DL, NUM2
MOV AH, 02H
INT 21h   


PRINT_LASTDIGIT:
MOV DL, NUM1
MOV AH, 02H
INT 21h 


EXIT:
MOV AH, 4Ch
INT 21h 
MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

Comment: Comment your code, especially if you want others to help. Also, describe the problem more precisely. Given that you have emu8086, step through your code and see where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking 2 digit Input, so after Multiplication you want to convert the answer back to it's original [decimal] form for displaying.
That can be done by dividing it by 10 and then displaying coefficient and Remainder accordingly, Here is a code for Multiplication that firstly takes a 2 digit numbers and then multiply it with another single digit number, 
But that is just to give you an Idea:

```
.model small
.stack
.data
msg1 db 10,13,'First Value:','$';
msg2 db 10,13,'Second Value:','$'; 
msg3 db 10,13,'multiplication:','$';
second db ?
temp db ?
num1 db ?
num2 db ?
a db 10 

.code
main proc
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax 
mov ah,09h
lea dx,msg1
int 21h
mov ah,01h
int 21h
sub al,30h
mul a
mov temp,al
mov ah,01h
int 21h
sub al,30h
add temp,al
mov [bx],al
mov ah,09h
lea dx,msg2
int 21h
mov ah,01h
int 21h
mov second,al
sub second,30h
mov ax,00h
mov al,temp
mul second
div a
mov num1,al
mov num2,ah
add num1,30h
add num2,30h 
mov ah,09h
lea dx,msg3
int 21h
mov ah,02h
mov dl,num1
int 21h
mov ah,02h
mov dl,num2
int 21h
mov al,0
inc bx
dec cx
mov ah,4ch
int 21h
main endp
end main
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Your code lacks comments so keep hoping that it'll help! It has inconsistensies and a very obvious error. Please rework your answer.

Comment: What I really want to appear in the Window is just like this: You enter 2 decimal numbers and the sum and product of that two numbers will be shown.